# Looped Ajax-called page unavailable after 90 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So hello community.

I develop a website generating large files via PHP, which can take up to 5 minutes. I raised the settings of PHP value for max execution time, no problem here.

When the user calls for the generated file, a loader is shown on the current page, this loader executes a looped Ajax request, reading a simple text file, containing the status of the file generation.
Ex: «Generating line 120/350».

This works fine, each time te ajax request provides a result, it calls itself again after 2.5 seconds. Until more or less 1 minute 30, then the log freezes. And i can't figure out what happens. This is what i got so far :

- There is no Apache crash, nor error in the log
- When i try to access my text file, after that freezing, via the browser, this latter keeps loading, without displaying. Until the file-generating script has finished. Then it displays my text file sayin "All done".
- Now the interesting part : if during this process, i access my text file with *an other browser*, the files is displayed just fine and every update of it in the borwser show the evolution of the log running! That is what bugs me most.
- So, server side, my text file IS generated and updated, until the end of the logging process (it updates correctly during all the file creation process). Just, accessing my text file is not possible with the same browser.
- This happens both locally and online.

Who can tell whe what happens / how to solve this issue?

**Jquery plugin (hand made) :**

```
;jQuery(function ($) {

// dynlog object
$.fn.dynlog = function(options){

    // user id MUST be defined
    if(typeof(uid) == "undefined"){
        console.log("Function dynlog: Missing current user ID!");
        return;
    }
    uid = parseInt( uid );

    // "$D" is current instance of the object
    var $D = this;

    // plugin's default options
    var defaults = {
        // frequency in milliseconds between two ajax checks of the log value
        // raise for optimisation, lower for user experience
        frequency: 1500
        , default_text: 'Chargement'

        // Callbacks
        , onStart: function() { return true;    }
        , onStop: function(inst) {  return true;    }
        , onInit: function(inst) {  return true;    }
    }

    // mergin defaults, and given params
    $D.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    // LOCAL VARS
    var   running = false
        , runningClass = false
        , return_txt
        , current_txt
        , client = new XMLHttpRequest() // For reading file
        , to // Timeout, with throttle
        ;


    // ///////////////////// 
    // METHODS: 

    // /////////////////
    // init
    $D.init = function(inst) {
        // external function
        $D.settings.onInit();
    }

    // /////////////////
    // Démarrer l'affichage du log
    $D.start = function(){
        running = true;

        // Adding class 'running' to container
        $D.find('.dynlog-container').addClass('running');

        // Let's go get the log value
        $D.fetch();
    }

    // /////////////////
    // Go seek log value
    $D.fetch = function(){
        // read log text file => see further fo "on-read" event
        client.open('GET', 'files/dynlog/'+uid+'.txt');
        client.send(null);
    }

    // /////////////////
    // Arréter l'affichage du log
    $D.stop = function(){

        // do not update anymore, please
        running = false;

        // removes running status fos visual update
        $D.find('.dynlog-container').removeClass('running');
        runningClass = false;

    }

    // /////////////////////
    // PRIVATE METHODS
    // /////////////////////

    // /////////////////
    // Update log visually
    var update = function(text){ 
        // Afficher le texte donné
        $D.find('.dynlog-container .dynlog-message').text( text );
    };


    // /////////////////////
    // ONCE FILE IS SEEKED
    // /////////////////////

    // /////////////////
    // What happens when file seeked ?
    client.onreadystatechange = function(){

        // Text to display in log
        return_txt = false;

        // If file is found
        if(client.status == 200){
            // its content is the text to display
            return_txt = client.responseText;
        }

        // If file NOT found or text is defined but null
        if(client.status == 404 || return_txt === ''){
            // please write the default value
            return_txt = $D.settings.default_text;
        }

        // if text is retuned AND different from previous
        if(return_txt != '' && return_txt != current_txt){
            // then please update it
            current_txt = return_txt;
            update( current_txt );
        }

        // cycle the call if we are still running
        if(client.status != 0 && running){
            // throttler :
            clearTimeout(to);
            // re-call the start stuff
            to = setTimeout(function(){
                // $D.start();
                $D.fetch();
            }, $D.settings.frequency);

        }

    };



    // /////////////////////
    // Applying plugin to jquery object
    $(this).each(function(){

        // création du template
        var tpl = '<div class="dynlog-container">'
                    +'<div class="dynlog-message"></div>'
                +'</div>'
                ;

        $(this).append(tpl);

    });


    // /////////////////////
    // call the "constructor" method
    $D.init(this);


    // /////////////////////
    // returns this instance
    return this;

}

});
```

**PHP script basically does:**

```
file_put_contents( $file, $contents);
```

Comment: Do you lock the file when you write to it so when the ajax tries to call it, it can't and so crashes?

Comment: can you add some code to this

Comment: @Pete i do not believe i do, since an other browser does access it during writing. I use PHP function `file_put_contents()` to write its contents.

Comment: PS : i actually included a test in my loop, still re-calling the ajax if the result failed.